# FTP XML file using FileZilla = malformed tag on receiving end?

Tags: xml, ftp

When sending an XML file to our FTP via FileZilla it appears somewhere in the transfer 1 or 2 of the XML tags are being malformed.

Our client has confirmed on their end that prior to the upload the file is solid and does not have any malformed tags.

Yet on the receiving end when we review the file there are malformed tags.  Not missing tags, but tags that have been broken into two lines.  The tags (only 1 or 2 total for each file) are random and I'm not seeing any similarities in where the malformations occur.

```
For example:
<customerNumber>blah blah blah</custome
erNumber>
```

I'm just looking for any guidance or suggestions seeing that my google searches are coming up empty.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you on z/OS?  I have observed this effect on that platform.  The only way I was able to fix it was to get the z/OS admins to set LRECL=80 and write a pre-processing script to remove every 80th byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making sure that you know whether or not your transferring in Binary mode or ASCII mode.   Also, is Filezilla using z-mode compression or not?   Also, are you sure that the format of your XML is as you would expect: for example, does your XML have a BOM and is it UTF-8 or UTF-16 or ANSI?

Comment: ASCII was the problem.  Turns out client had a new computer and was transferring ASCII.  I had them change to Binary and transfer was successful.